# JQuery on IOS is slow, jumpy and jerky

Tags: jquery, ios, smoothing

Our site uses a great deal of JQuery, but on iOS effects such as fade, slide etc.. are jumpy at best. They are not smooth such as those seen on web apps on on native apps.

How does one achieve this smoothness seen on such web apps.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

EG.
Have a look at this page. It uses slide and fade effects all fairly crap on the iPAD
http://www.divethegap.com/update/diving-trips/master-scuba-diver#

Comment: Do you have some example code? It may help.

Comment: @Agos :: EDITED question with an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [CSS3 Transforms](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html) and transitions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Allow me to expand a moment. This admin panel we would like it to be themed rather like the mail and settings pages on the iPad. At the moment I cannot see to have two scrollable columns and a fixed header on the iOS web browser. How would one achieve this.

Comment: Mobile Safari doesn't support position:fixed (though you can <a href="http://code.google.com/mobile/articles/webapp_fixed_ui.html">roll your own</a>), and internally scrolling divs require an awkward two-finger scroll by the user. I don't recommend trying this UI technique in Mobile Safari.